# Как правильно задать в задаче путь к файлу? Пишет ошибку FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2012BoysNames.txt'

Tags: python

Хочу задать вопрос по задаче.
Задача следующая:

> Некоторые имена, такие как Бен, Джонатан и Эндрю, подходят только
> для мальчиков, другие – Ребекка или Флора – только для девочек. Но есть и универсальные имена наподобие Крис или Алекс, которые могут носить
> и мальчики, и девочки.
> Напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран имена, ис-
> пользованные для мальчиков и девочек в указанном пользователем
> году. Если в этом году универсальных имен не было, нужно известить
> об этом пользователя. Кроме того, если за указанный пользователем год
> не было данных по именам, выведите соответствующее сообщение об
> ошибке.

Вот пример кода:

```
from pathlib import Path
first_year = 1900
last_year = 2012

def Universal_names(fname, names):
    inf = open(fname, "r")
    line = inf.readline()
    inf.close()
    parts = line.split()
    name = parts[0]

    if name not in names:
        names.append(name)

def main():
    boys = []
    girls = []
    uni_names = []

    for year in range(first_year, last_year + 1):
        boys_fname = str(year) + str(Path("BoysNames.txt"))
        girls_fname = str(year) + str(Path("GirlsNames.txt"))
        uni_names_fname = str(year) + str(Path("Универсальные имена.txt"))

    if boys_fname == uni_names_fname:
        uni_names_fname.append(boys_fname)
    elif girls_fname == uni_names_fname:
        uni_names_fname.append(girls_fname)


    Universal_names(boys_fname, boys)
    Universal_names(girls_fname, girls)
    Universal_names(uni_names_fname, uni_names)


    print("Универсальные имена:")
    for name in uni_names:
        print(" ", name)
        print()

main()
```

Кто может, подскажите что можно сделать.

Comment: В чем проблема? Ошибка вышла, или не работает?

Comment: А есть такой файл в каталоге запуска программы?

Comment: Поправьте отступы и форматирование, потом поговорим. Но навскидку, у вас нет той этого файла там где нужно. А должен он быть в той же папке, что и программа. Иначе нужно менять указываемый к ней путь в программе

Comment: @ЮрычBRO Поправил

Comment: @CrazyElf да, у меня папка с файлами в каталоге